# Exception Handling with DB express

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-2010, dbexpress

I am migrating our application from BDE to DBexpress in Delphi2010.We are connecting to Sybase Database.

The exceptions raised by stored procedure using raiseerror message was getting captured by BDE but the same is not happening with DBexpress.

Eg the stored proc contains the below statement if any validation fails

select @msg = "Could not perform the edit because another user has changed the record "

if @field1 <> @field2
  raiserror 20999 @msg
  return
end

Is there any way to catch this exception with DB express.

or Is it a bug in dbexpress?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it is a bug with dbexpress, I'm using an exception raised in a firebird sp without problem. I believe the driver you're using is failing to raise an appropriate exception when the client library returns an error.

Comment: Thanks,Could you please let me know Is there any Sybase drivers?

Comment: I used VISOCO sybase drivers in Delphi 7 - not sure if they are up to date anymore, but they worked great.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at

http://www.delphigroups.info/2/9/753836.html